tkinter no muestra algunos widgets en Mac OS
tengo este código de Python que usa tkinter para hacer una interfaz minimalista de una código de historiales de animales
root = tk.Tk()

label_nombre = tk.Label(root, text="Nombre")
label_nombre.pack()

entry_nombre = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
entry_nombre.pack()

label_raza = tk.Label(root, text="Raza")
label_raza.pack()

entry_raza = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
entry_raza.pack()

label_edad = tk.Label(root, text="Edad")
label_edad.pack()

entry_edad = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
entry_edad.pack()

button_guardar = tk.Button(root, text="Guardar", command=guardar)
button_guardar.pack()

button_mostrar = tk.Button(root, text="Mostrar", command=mostrar)
button_mostrar.pack()
root.update()
root.mainloop()`

pero cuando ejecuto no muestra error pero solo se muestran en la ventana de tkinter los botones, lo que no aparece es lo demás, per si están porque según pasas el ratón vez que cambia al pasar por el entry y y recepción las letras.
que es lo que podría estar pasando?
por si sirve de algo he cambiado de windows a Mac OS

¿Que versión de MAC OS, de Python y de tcl/tk usas? Si estás usando la versión de tcl/tk que provee Mac Os por defecto, seguramente ese sea el problema, si nada ha cambiado es antigua y con un numero considerable de bugs... Prueba a instalar desde brew (brew update brew install tcl-tk
brew link tcl-tk --force) una versión reciente de tcl-tk y usa una versión actualizada de Python, te recomiendo usar pyenv en *nix (Mac/Linux) para manejar distintas versions de Python sin interferir con las instalcaiones del sistema.

genial, lo que me dijiste era. mil gracias
